# How to evaluate an expression

Tags: summation, list-manipulation, group-theory, products

I have a 3-dimensional array of numbers say A. I want to evaluate the following expression.

$\displaystyle\sum_{\sigma,\tau \in S_6}(\Pi_{i=1}^6A(i,\sigma(i),\tau(i)))$. $S_6$ is the symmetric group in 6 variables.

How can I evaluate this in Mathematica?

Comment: A good starting place would be the documentation for [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html), [`Product`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product.html), and [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).

Comment: You will get more help if you provide us with an example of your matrix as all as the sigma and tau indices (variables?).